# javascript 'this' references wrong scope

Tags: javascript, knockout.js, scope

I'm trying to create a ViewModel in javascript, part of the the viewmodel's functionality is to load data from web and display it on ui side. I run into a problem because I am unable to reference the viewmodel object in a certain callback function. Here is the situation:

```
LoggedInViewModel.prototype = {
getFriendList: function() {
    var self = this; // 'this' references the correct viewmodel object
    $.ajax({
        url: "api/users/friendlist",
        success: self.loadFriendListIntoModel
    });
},
loadFriendListIntoModel: function (friends) {
    var self = this;
    //'this' references the ajax object that called the function.
    // is there a way to make 'this' reference the actual viewmodel 
    // object here? i can do var self = model; but that feels hacky
    friends.forEach(function (friend) {
        //Uncaught TypeError: Cannot call method 'push' of undefined 
        self.friendList.push(new Friend(friend));
    });
}
};

var model = new LoggedInViewModel();
ko.applyBindings(model);
model.getFriendList();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can fix it like this:

```
getFriendList: function() {
    $.ajax({
        url: "api/users/friendlist",
        success: this.loadFriendListIntoModel,
        context: this
    });
},
```

or like this:

```
getFriendList: function() {
    var self = this; // 'this' references the correct viewmodel object
    $.ajax({
        url: "api/users/friendlist",
        success: function() {
            self.loadFriendListIntoModel();
        }
    });
},
```

or like this:

```
getFriendList: function() {
    $.ajax({
        url: "api/users/friendlist",
        success: $.proxy(this.loadFriendListIntoModel, this)
    });
},
```

Read [$.ajax](https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/) for context option and about [$.proxy](https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.proxy/). You could also use [Function.prototype.bind](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/bind) method.